# Declaration the variable in list or record

Tags: c#, arrays

I wrote this code in C# language to create a list or record, the record contains an array named `Y` and a variable named `xyx`. The problem is how to initialize the variable `xyx`. ًWhen I run a program there appears a problem in defining this variable

Declaration:

```
public struct All_Frames
{
    public int[,] Y;

    public int xyx;

};

All_Frames Frame = new All_Frames();
List<All_Frames> Frames = new List<All_Frames>();
```

In main program:

```
Frame.Y = new int[width, height];
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
   for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
       Frame.Y[x, y] = (int)(0.299 * Red[x, y] + 0.587 * Green[x, y]);


Frames.Add(Frame);
```

How can I initialize the variable `xyx`?

Comment: _there appears a problem_ What is the problem? Also remove the C++ tag.

Comment: don't use struct when you have reference fields. that can cause weird behaviors that you may not expect. use class instead which is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is how to initialize the variable xyx

```
All_Frames Frame = new All_Frames();

Frame.Y   = new int[width, height];
Frame.xyx = 100; // Or another value
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way you did with the array, you can access direct the member xyx...

```
Frame.xyx = 117;
```

Comment: Also there is a problem even after the value has been developed

Answer (score 0):

This may helps

```
Frame.Y = new int[width, height];
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
   for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
   {
       Frame.Y[x, y] = (int)(0.299 * Red[x, y] + 0.587 * Green[x, y]);
       Frame.xyx = 1213; // Set your value here
   }


Frames.Add(Frame);
```

Comment: Also there is a problem even after the value has been developed

Comment: What is the problem? I it can be stated here, consider editing your post and if that a completely new problem you may want to post it as a new question.

Comment: -I set the value but there is error when run the program "xyx is a not variable"

Comment: We cannot guess what the problem is. So you may want to edit your code sample and show where is not going as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem/question correctly, you are looking for a way to initialize the variable `xyx` at the time of the creation of the `struct`. I would add a constructor to the `struct` and initialize everything there.  This way, you don't have to declare the struct and then have another call to initialize the array, just do it all in the constructor.  Doing this, you can eliminate this line of code:

```
Frame.Y = new int[width, height];
```

and you can replace it with a call to the constructor

```
All_Frames Frame = new All_Frames(width, height, 1234); // or whatever value you want for xyx

public struct All_Frames
{
    public int[,] Y;

    public int xyx;

    public All_Frames(int width, int height, int initXyx)
    {
        Y = new int[width, height];
        xyx = initXyx;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also there is a problem even after the value has been developed

Comment: @ZainabJawad - I am not sure what you mean.  What is the problem? What do you mean "problem after it has been developed"?  You can set the value by accessing it directly.

Comment: @pstrjds-yes, i set the value but there is error when run the program "xyx is a not variable"

Comment: @ZainabJawad - Then you must have some other typo in your code. There is an extra semicolon at the end of your struct, maybe that is causing some other issues.  Maybe you typed `xyz` in your struct and `xyx` in your code.